# Samba not allowing me into the workgroup?

Tags: samba

I am getting a rather frustrating problem with Samba. I am not much of a dancer, and I'd rather do the cha cha cha... okay all jokes aside:

[image]

Why do I get this? I have tried every fix I could find, but nothing works. Here is the contents of smb.conf:

http://pastebin.com/BjY3ZDtf

Comment: This is normal (isnt it ?). You can leave domain as "WORKGROUP" (I presume thats what its saying, you just enter the username and password of a user on the target machine that you have allowed access to the files.

Comment: But... it's not supposed to ask for a password when you are trying to enter the domain, or if you enable guest access.

Comment: Ahh! I am thinking workgroup not domain. Have you entered the username "guest" ? Is their a guest password set on the server ?

Comment: There is no "server" really. It is just two systems (sometimes 3) that are set to share files. I can't even view my own local system because of this prompt, and enabling the guest account doesn't work (nor does entering "guest").

Comment: Is the machine hosting the shared files a windows macine ? (And hence the need to use samba). If so, can you create a user on that windows machine with the same name as the user on your linux box you are trying to connect from. Turn of simple file sharing (if it is enabled) and explicitly allow read/write access to your shared folder by that user.

Comment: @hatterman it's only Linux (there is a Windows machine in the house but I'm not trying to access it). I can't even view the files of the machine I'm on from the network. It keeps asking for this username and password **even with guest sharing enabled**.

Comment: you've  got a log file for files connecting - pastebin this? /usr/local/samba/var/ - also your smb.conf doesnt have explicit folders defined that is to be shared - why? You appear just to have printers shared.  Which SAMBA have you installed - samba 3 or samba 4?

Comment: @fossfreedom 4. I do have folders shared (using nautilus-share or whatever it's called). This used to work in the past. I will post the log later. I have tried the method of sharing files using smb.conf and even THAT didn't work.

Comment: Have you set yourself up as a SAMBA user ? If you have shared files using nautilus, but your username is not part of the SAMBA group, then it will not work. This can be done from the command line or from the SAMBA GUI. I think the command line is 'smbpasswd -a <username>', a quick google should tell you.

Comment: @hatterman I added myself to the samba and sambashare groups, restarted smbd and nmbd, restarted nautilus, tried again and still got the same problem.

Comment: @fossfreedom there is no such file or folder.

Comment: In your samba.conf file, do you have the following 2 lines at the top of the global section ? "wins support = yes" and "name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast" (without the quotes, I don't know how to insert new lines here !).

Comment: Also, have you added the user "guest" to /etc/passwd ? If not, try using the user name "nobody".

Comment: I've tried the resolve order fix and that didn't work either.

Comment: silly suggestion: try with nemo instead of nautilus - I have to do that to access resources via VPN in my workplace.

Comment: @guntbert exactly how is that going to solve the problem if it is at a lower level? Even Dolphin doesn't work :/

I can see my father's laptop (a Windows system, running Windows 7), under "Workgroup". I can't access any files but that's okay cause I haven't set it to share any. However, with my own systems running Ubuntu I can't get into my own workgroup or access files over Samba even on the same system sharing the files.

Comment: @RolandiXor, not as a solution of course - more like a jiggle for trying - from my own experience with access to shares in a windows domain.

Comment: Delete the shares in samba.conf, restart samba (just reboot for completeness). Then use nautilus to share a folder, does that work ?

Comment: @hatterman I've done that :( and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the system from which you are sharing the files set a password for the samba user-name  using the command :

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <user-name>
```

In the smb.conf file (/etc/samba/smb.conf) files set the share directory in the following way and force the user-name. This will allow you to login using that user-name and password from other system. Set the writable to no for read-only access.

[ShareName]

```
path = <absolute path of folder to be shared>
available = yes
valid users = <user-name>
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
force user = <user-name>
```

Note: there should be a single space both before and after each of the equal signs.

Now from the other system login using the user-name and password to access the share.

Comment: Is [ShareName] supposed to be in the codeblock?

Comment: P.S. this still won't allow me to get into the computer in question with just guest access (which worked before), and probably not at all since I can't even view what folders there are on any share.